# Reading from File and store in differernt arrays

Tags: c++

I need coding for reading from File and store in differernt arrays !!!

for eg :

> paul 23 54
>
> john 32 56

My requirement are as follows: I need to store `paul,john` in string array and `23,32` in one integer array; and similarly `54,56` in another `int` array.

I read the inputs from the file and print it but I am unable to save in 3 different arrays.

```
int main()
{
    string name;
    int score;
    ifstream inFile ;
     
    inFile.open("try.txt");
    while(getline(inFile,name))
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
    }
    inFile.close();     
    
}
```

So kindly suggest me some logics for doin this and I would really appreciate that... !!!

Comment: You are missing data structure such as; Array, Arraylist, Linkedlist and Vectors. You need the data structure to hold the input data and to store it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are new to programming? Or new to C++?  So I provided the sample code to get you started. :)

```
#include <string>;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> name;
    vector<int> veca, vecb;
    string n;
    int a, b;

    ifstream fin("try.txt");
    while (fin >> n >> a >> b) {
       name.push_back(n);
       veca.push_back(a);
       vecb.push_back(b);
       cout << n << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << endl;
    }
    fin.close()

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::string fileToRead = "file.log";
    std::vector<int> column2, column3;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    int number1, number2;
    std::string strName;

    std::fstream fileStream(fileToRead, std::ios::in);
    while (fileStream>> strName >> number1 >> number2)
    {
       names.push_back(strName);
       column2.push_back(number1);
       column3.push_back(number2);
       std::cout << "Value1=" << strName
           << "; Value2=" << number1
           << "; value2=" << number2
           << std::endl;
    }
    fileStream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to read the first column in file to a string (strName) and then push it to a vector (names). Similarly, second and third columns are read into number1 and number2 first and then pushed into vectors named column1 and column2, respectively.

Running it will get you the following results:

```
Value1=paul; Value2=23; value2=54
Value1=john; Value2=32; value2=56
```